# HttpHandler on a file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, scripting, httphandler

I have a following setup. I have a web application and in the .css of this application I define a background image to be presented when I hover over some element.

I want a script or something of that sort that sits on the server and when the image is accessed, it calls an action on the application. Unfortunately, I have no idea where to begin.

I want to know if and some hints on how to write a server side component that executes an action in web application based on the request for a file by css.

I am on Windows7, ASP.NET MVC.

**EDIT**

So, I have followed your suggestions on using httpHandlers. It seems like the perfect solution. However, I am running into problems.

I have followed this very helpful link http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/ but I was just unable to get a hit on a route

```
routes.Add("ImageRouting", new Route("Content/themes/base/images/{filename}.png", new ImageRouteHandler()));
```

My only other route is the one generated by default by MVC template.

So I figured out that the requests to a file are not handled by default by MVC. So I had to fix that by by setting the `RouteExistingFiles` property of the `RouteCollection` to `true`.

Now I get proper hits on my images but for some reason, `Site.css` located in `Content` folder is not used to style the resulting html.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean by "when the image is accessed" when it is requested by a client? That would break e.g. if the browser pre-loads resources. What are you trying to achieve, and OS and web server are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an HttpHandler in your machine.config or web.config like so:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="supported http verbs" path="path" type="namespace.classname, assemblyname" />
<httpHandlers>
```

Your verb can be "*" or "GET", set path equal to the location of your image file on the server, and fill the type variables according to your namespace, class and handler function.

For a more detailed explanation, see:
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you use asp.net you can define `ashx` handler that gives image to client, and performs any action you want. You canr read  more here:

- http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx
- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/283.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your focus is the image in the CSS file, you could make a script handle the serving of the image used in your CSS file but this won't be triggered everytime the visitor hovers over some element, let alone everytime they load a new page due to caching, unless you have some strict no-caching rules in play.

If you're more interested in every time someone hovers some element, you could just trigger an AJAX request and go from there.

```
$('.some-element').hover(function(){ $.get("spy.aspx"); });
```

Comment: I am interested only in the css way, but thanks for the useful tip about caching.